# Flutter: Firebase push notification onResume and onLunch callBack not received in iOS; same works in android

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on the firebase push notification in ios project and I am successfully receiving the notification for the iOS and Android both but for the iOS I am not able to receive `onResume` and `onLanch` call back in the flutter side when I tap on the notification.

Firebase_messaging is updated on the latest version (`firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16`)

- **Firebase configuration:**

```
     setFirebase() async {
        _fireBaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
            const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    
        _fireBaseMessaging.configure(
          // ignore: missing_return
          onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
            print('onMessage $msg');
          },
    
          onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) async {
             print('onResume $msg');

          },

          onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) async {
             print('onLaunch $msg');

          },
        );
    
        _fireBaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
            .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
    
              print("IOS NOTIFICATION SETTING");
        });
      }
```

- For the same code, I am receiving the acknowledge of `onLanch` and
  `onResume` in my android app.
- **AppDelegate.swift:**

```
      @UIApplicationMain
        @objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate{
           
            override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
                
                FirebaseApp.configure()
        
                GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
                
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
                    
                    // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
                    if granted
                    {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                        })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("Don't Allow")
                    }
                }
                
                return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
            }
            
            override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
            {
                completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you using an ios emulator?

Comment: No, I am using real device.